# How to send a Spark dataframe as a JSON/string input stream to a REST API endpoint without having to save it first?

Tags: json, api, apache-spark, inputstream

I have an ETL pipeline where the current flow is to extract some data from a Hive table, do some transformations on it, save it as a Parquet file and then read that data as a byte stream using an AWS S3 client. Then send that as an input stream to a REST API endpoint. Is there a way I can do this *without* having to save the data as a Parquet file first? Can I convert the dataframe to a JSON input stream?

I know that I can do `toJSON.collect()`, but that doesn't work for me because it gets all the data distributed in different executors to the driver and the driver would run out of memory. Can I keep the data distributed in different executors and just have every partition be sent as a batch to the REST API endpoint as an input stream?

Comment: You can use `foreachPartition` to send without collecting but this will be seen as N different requests from the server, is this possible with the server you are sending the data to or does it need a unique request will all data?

Comment: Also, saving it first might look like an unoptimized version but it's often a good design because it decorrelates processing the data and sending them. You can easily retry just the sending part without having to relaunch processing for instance.

Comment: Thank you @GaëlJ. We open a batch with the endpoint and then send multiple files as individual requests tagged with that batch to the endpoint. So sending n different requests is great!